# Getting a Reference Error when starting my react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am getting a reference Error message: can't find variable:error, i'm not able to figure out where I have written this variable in code. Someone help!!

[image]

[image]

This is my App.js (Starting point)

```
import React from 'react';
import Main from './components/MainComponent';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConfigureStore } from './redux/configureStore';

const store = ConfigureStore();
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
      <Main />
    </Provider>
     
    );
  }
}
```

ActionTypes.js (This file represents different Actions which can be dispatched)

```
export const DISHES_LOADING = 'DISHES_LOADING';
export const ADD_DISHES = 'ADD_DISHES';
export const DISHES_FAILED = 'DISHES_FAILED';
export const ADD_COMMENTS = 'ADD_COMMENTS';
export const COMMENTS_FAILED = 'COMMENTS_FAILED';
export const PROMOS_LOADING = 'PROMOS_LOADING';
export const ADD_PROMOS = 'ADD_PROMOS';
export const PROMOS_FAILED = 'PROMOS_FAILED';
export const LEADERS_LOADING = 'LEADERS_LOADING';
export const ADD_LEADERS = 'ADD_LEADERS';
export const LEADERS_FAILED = 'LEADERS_FAILED';
```

ActionCreators.js (This file fetches data from a fake Rest api and performs the necessary computations dispatches the data and action accordingly )

```
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import { dishes } from './dishes';
import { comments } from './comments';
import { promotions } from './promotions';
import { leaders } from './leaders';

export const ConfigureStore = () => {
    const store = createStore(
        combineReducers({
            dishes,
            comments,
            promotions,
            leaders
        }),
        applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)
    );

    return store;
}
```

AboutComponent.js (This is one of my component)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Text, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { Card } from 'react-native-elements';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { baseUrl } from '../shared/baseUrl';
import { Loading } from './LoadingComponent';


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        leaders: state.leaders
    }
}

function History() {
    return(
        <Card   title="Our History">
            <Text style={{margin: 10}}>
                Started in 2010, Ristorante con Fusion quickly established itself as a culinary icon par excellence in Hong Kong. With its unique brand of world fusion cuisine that can be found nowhere else, it enjoys patronage from the A-list clientele in Hong Kong.  Featuring four of the best three-star Michelin chefs in the world, you never know what will arrive on your plate the next time you visit us.{"\n\n"}

                The restaurant traces its humble beginnings to The Frying Pan, a successful chain started by our CEO, Mr. Peter Pan, that featured for the first time the world's best cuisines in a pan.

            </Text>
        </Card>
    );
}

function RenderLeaders(props) {

    const leaders = props.leaders;
            
    const renderLeaderItems = ({item, index}) => {
        
        return (
            <ListItem
                key={index}
                title={item.name}
                subtitle={item.description}
                hideChevron={true}
                leftAvatar={{source: {uri: baseUrl + item.image}}}
          />
        );
    };

    return (
        <Card title='Comments' >
            <FlatList 
                data={leaders}
                renderItem={renderLeaderItems}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
            />
        </Card>
    );
}

class About extends Component {

 

    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'About Us'
    };

    
    render(){

        if (this.props.leaders.isLoading) {
            return(
                <ScrollView>
                    <History />
                    <Card
                        title='Corporate Leadership'>
                        <Loading />
                    </Card>
                </ScrollView>
            );
        }
        else if (this.props.leaders.errMess) {
            return(
                <ScrollView>
                    <History />
                    <Card
                        title='Corporate Leadership'>
                        <Text>{this.props.leaders.errMess}</Text>
                    </Card>
                </ScrollView>
            );
        }
        else{
            return (
                      <ScrollView>
                        <History/>
                        <RenderLeaders leaders={this.props.leaders.leaders} />
                      </ScrollView>
            )    
        }
   
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(About);
```

MainComponent.js (The file which controls the side drawer and navigation)

```
import React, {Component } from 'react';
import Menu from './MenuComponent';
import DishDetail from './DishdetailComponent';
import { View, Platform, Image, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Text } from 'react-native';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createAppContainer, SafeAreaView } from 'react-navigation';
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerItems } from 'react-navigation-drawer'; 
import Home from './HomeComponent';
import Contact from './ContactComponent';
import About from './AboutComponent';
import {Icon} from 'react-native-elements';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchDishes, fetchComments, fetchPromos, fetchLeaders } from '../redux/ActionCreators';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
  
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchDishes: () => dispatch(fetchDishes()),
  fetchComments: () => dispatch(fetchComments()),
  fetchPromos: () => dispatch(fetchPromos()),
  fetchLeaders: () => dispatch(fetchLeaders()),
})



const MenuNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Menu:{screen:Menu,
    navigationOptions:({navigation}) => ({
      headerLeft: <Icon  name='menu' size={24} color='white'
        onPress={()=>navigation.toggleDrawer()}
        />
    })},
  DishDetail: { screen: DishDetail }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Menu',
  navigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#512DA8"
      },
      headerTintColor: '#fff',
      headerTitleStyle: {
          color: "#fff"            
      }
  }
});


const HomeNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home }
}, {
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#512DA8"
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
        color: "#fff"            
    },
    headerTintColor: "#fff",
      headerLeft: <Icon  name='menu' size={24} color='white'
      onPress={()=>navigation.toggleDrawer()}
    />
  })
});

const AboutNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: About }
}, {
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#512DA8"
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
        color: "#fff"            
    },
    headerTintColor: "#fff",
    headerLeft: <Icon  name='menu' size={24} color='white'
      onPress={()=>navigation.toggleDrawer()}
    />  
  })
});

const ContactNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Contact }
}, {
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#512DA8"
    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
        color: "#fff"            
    },
    headerTintColor: "#fff",
    headerLeft: <Icon  name='menu' size={24} color='white'
      onPress={()=>navigation.toggleDrawer()}
    />  
  })
});

const CustomDrawerContentComponent = (props) => (
  <ScrollView>
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container} forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
      <View style={styles.drawerHeader}>
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <Image source={require('./images/logo.png')} style={styles.drawerImage} />
        </View>
        <View style={{flex: 2}}>
          <Text style={styles.drawerHeaderText}>Ristorante Con Fusion</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      <DrawerItems {...props} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  </ScrollView>
);


const MainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: 
    { screen: HomeNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Home',
        drawerLabel: 'Home',
        drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
          <Icon
            name='home'
            type='font-awesome'
            size={24}
            color={tintColor}
          />
        )
      }
    },
  About: 
    { screen: AboutNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'About Us',
        drawerLabel: 'About Us',
        drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
          <Icon
            name='info-circle'
            type='font-awesome'
            size={24}
            color={tintColor}
          />
        )
      }
    },
  Menu: 
    { screen: MenuNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Menu',
        drawerLabel: 'Menu',
        drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
          <Icon
            name='list'
            type='font-awesome'
            size={24}
            color={tintColor}
          />
        )
      }, 
    },
  Contact:{
      screen:ContactNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Contact Us',
        drawerLabel: 'Contact Us',
        drawerIcon: ({tintColor}) => (
          <Icon
            name='address-card'
            type='font-awesome'
            size={22}
            color={tintColor}
          />
        )
      }
  }  
}, {
drawerBackgroundColor: '#D1C4E9',
contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent
});
const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

class Main extends Component {
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchDishes();
    this.props.fetchComments();
    this.props.fetchPromos();
    this.props.fetchLeaders();
  }

  onDishSelect(dishId) {
    this.setState({selectedDish: dishId})
}
  render() {
 
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : Expo.Constants.statusBarHeight }}>
      <App />
  </View>
        
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  drawerHeader: {
    backgroundColor: '#512DA8',
    height: 140,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row'
  },
  drawerHeaderText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  },
  drawerImage: {
    margin: 10,
    width: 80,
    height: 60
  }
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);
```

Comment: Could you please edit your post to include your code?

Comment: sure @cbr, adding it.

Comment: @cbr, I have added the code.

Comment: The error suggests that it's originating from `Main`. Please show `MainComponent` as well.

Comment: sure @cbr, adding it

Comment: @cbr, I have added MainComponent.js. Please review.

Comment: You're attempting to import fetchXXXXX from `../redux/ActionCreators` in MainComponent.js. If that refers to your `ActionCreators.js`, notice that you're not exporting these functions in that file. Perhaps you meant to import these functions from their specific files, or re-export them in ActionCreators.js with `export { dishes } from './dishes'` etc